# org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException with Kotlin and sealed classes

Tags: kotlin, spring-data

I am having issues with spring data (elasticsearch) and Kotlin sealed classes. It seems it's detecting two id mappings. The classes:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "@type")
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AbstractSectionV1Dto.HtmlSectionV1Dto::class, name = "HTML"))
sealed class AbstractSectionV1Dto(
    open val number: Int?,
    open val id: Long?,
    open val questionAnswers: List<AbstractQuestionAnswerV1Dto>,
    open val rightQuestionAnswers: Int?,
    open val questionAnswersSize: Int?) : Dto {

data class HtmlSectionV1Dto(
        override val number: Int?,
        override val id: Long,
        override val questionAnswers: List<AbstractQuestionAnswerV1Dto>,
        override val rightQuestionAnswers: Int?,
        override val questionAnswersSize: Int?,
        val html: String?) : AbstractSectionV1Dto(number, id, questionAnswers, rightQuestionAnswers, questionAnswersSize)
(...)
}
```

when I save the document to elasticsearch, I get

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Attempt to add id property private final java.lang.Long com.package.AbstractSectionV1Dto.id but already have property private final long com.package.AbstractSectionV1Dto$TextSectionV1Dto.id registered as id. Check your mapping configuration!
```

I also tried setting @Id only on the top class and on both. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working by placing org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient in the sealed class id, but it would be nice if someone could confirm or say something about the best solution to this problem.